# Rails Ajax call from controller to view & update div inside view

Tags: ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am newbie to Ajax. When other existing function in javascript get execute, I want to excute this ajax function call from controller to view i.e fetch the latest @trip model from controller and update the div of this code without refreshing the whole page.  i searched online and here, and i found ajax request from view to controller but not from controller to view via div update/reload. 
any help is appreciate.

Controller:

```
def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    ....

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
        <p><hr/></p>
        <h3>Activity Record</h3>
        <div style="color:black;">
        <% @trip.activities.each do |a| %>
        <%= a.created_at.strftime("%m.%d.%Y %T") rescue nil %> - <%= a.description %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <%= @trip.created_at.strftime("%m.%d.%Y %T") rescue nil %> - <b>Image Received</b><br/>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On view, I gave div id name of 'activityHistory'

```
 <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p><hr/></p>
                    <h3>Activity Record</h3>
                    <div id="activityHistory" style="color:black;">
                        <% @trip.activities.each do |a| %>
                              <%= a.created_at.strftime("%m.%d.%Y %T") rescue nil %> - <%= a.description %><br/>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= @trip.created_at.strftime("%m.%d.%Y %T") rescue nil %> - <b>Image Received</b><br/>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and used this javascript function to reload the div everytime the trigger event button is clicked

```
//this method refresh div, show latest history activity and relies on pusher event
    function reloadLatestActivityDiv(){
        $("#activityHistory").load('/trips/<%=@trip.id%> #activityHistory');
    }
```